# Howto pass ENC parameters to a puppet apply run?

Tags: puppet

To test my puppet modules I usually just use `puppet apply` on a virtual machine. In that testing scenario there is no puppet master or ENC available.

Lot's of my modules use parameters. So how do I test the module with different parameters without the need to hardcode them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the class with parameters as you would in a manifest, e.g.

```
class { 'foo':
  param1 => 'value',
}
```

`puppet apply` can take a manifest either as an argument to `-e`, in a file or on stdin, so you could run:

```
puppet apply -e "class { 'foo': param1 => 'value', param2 => 'value2' }"
```

or put the `class { 'foo': ... }` into test.pp and run `puppet apply test.pp`.

Or lastly, run `puppet apply`, type/paste the `class { 'foo': ... }` content into stdin and press `Ctrl+D` to end input and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you are using at least Puppet 3, your easiest course of action would probably be to set up Hiera in the test environment and rely on automated data binding to assign values to class parameters.  Indeed, this is *also* the best idea for binding data to class parameters on the master, and using the same approach in your test environment would give you the opportunity to test data and manifests together.

Comment: I'm using theforeman as an ENC. So for me there is no actual usecase for hiera. m0dlx's solution works best for me. Hiera is still a good way, if one uses hiera in production.